# How to change the ActionBar in Android

Tags: android

I want to put a custom Layout in ActionBar. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to target an Android SDK version < 11 (Honeycomb 3.0), ActionBarSherlock is definitely better than ActionBarCompat, the official solution for backwards compatibility offered by Google. Otherwise if you're developing using only APIs >= 11 use the default ActionBar because ABS implements nothing more than that.

[Here](http://corner.squareup.com/2012/05/actionbarsherlock-as-a-base.html) you can find an article written by Jake Wharton (the developer of ABS) where he discusses different ActionBar solutions pros and cons.

OR simply you can go through [Official site](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Comment: Please note that `ActionBarSherlock` is no longer supported nor developed by its author (last developed: 1 year ago).

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [the official Android doc ?](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

You'll find there some explanations about how to customize the ActionBar :

> To change the action bar background, create a custom theme for your activity that overrides the actionBarStyle property. This property points to another style in which you can override the background property to specify a drawable resource for the action bar background.
>
> To modify the color of text in the action bar, you need to override separate properties for each text element

If you're looking for much deepeer changes, [here you go](http://www.actionbarstylegenerator.com/)

Hope this helps you !

Answer (score 0):

you can use Actionbar style generator. It's the easiest way. just visit http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/